# Uploading files to Azure storage container from html5 directly

Tags: javascript, html, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

For my scenario, I am trying to allow a user to drag and drop files to a webpage using javascript that would be uploaded to a container, upload the files similar to how wordpress media uploading works from the administrative side.  The problem I am having is that I found code for creating a SAS url for the container,

```
        //Set the expiry time and permissions for the container.
        //In this case no start time is specified, so the shared access signature becomes valid immediately.
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
        sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24);
        sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write;

        //Generate the shared access signature on the container, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
        string sasContainerToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

        //Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
        return container.Uri + sasContainerToken;
```

but all of the examples I found seem to indicate that I have to generate a sas url for each blob

```
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        //Get a reference to a container to use for the sample code, and create it if it does not exist.
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        //Create a new stored access policy and define its constraints.
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPolicy sharedPolicy = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
            Permissions = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write
        };

        //Get the container's existing permissions.
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobContainerPermissions permissions = container.GetPermissions();//new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobContainerPermissions();

        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sharedPolicy);
```

instead as if I am uploading one file.

An administrator can upload any number of files, so to have to generate a blob sas via web api call for each one of these files seems to be very inefficient.  I would prefer to generate a SAS for the container and allow the user to upload to that container for a specified time, say 3 hours.  Also, I would like to use chunking to upload each file.  Would this be possible or would I have to generate a blob sas url for each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An administrator can upload any number of files, so to have to
>   generate a blob sas via web api call for each one of these files seems
>   to be very inefficient. I would prefer to generate a SAS for the
>   container and allow the user to upload to that container for a
>   specified time, say 3 hours.

It is certainly possible. When you create a SAS on a blob container with `Write` permission (for uploading purpose), same can be used for uploading multiple blobs in that container. You just have to construct blob URI based on the file being uploaded and append the SAS token. So for example, you created a SAS token for `mycontainer` container in `myaccount` storage account and uploading a file `myfile.png`, your SAS URL would be `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfile.png?SAS-Token`.

I noticed in your code that you're returning container URI with SAS token. In this case, you just have to insert the file name after container name to get blob upload URI.

> Also, I would like to use chunking to upload each file.

It is again possible. I wrote a few blog posts about this some time back which you may find useful:

http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/ (This was written before CORS support in Azure Storage so please ignore my comments about CORS in the post).

http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/

Comment: I have read and reviewed your examples, they are really good.  I referenced your chunking example in a single file upload scenario.  So, in this case my web api call would generate everything around "myfile.png" and I would just need javascript to add the appropriate file name as it cycled through the files to upload.  For example, my web api call could create something like this https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/search-replace?SAS-Token and javascript could just replace search-replace with the appropriate filename?

Comment: That is correct. If you look at the code in the 1st link. it is already doing it there. BTW, we have a free utility for uploading blobs directly in your storage account which makes use of the code mentioned in the post. Feel free to check it out if you don't want to write something of your own: http://cloudportam.com/features/storage/blob-receiver.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I greatly appreciate it.